# How to Submit form with validation

Tags: jquery

How to submit a form when status is 0?

```js
$(".form-validation").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  //check requst product blank field
  var Status = 0;
  $('.requiredCheck').each(function() {
    var blank_value = $.trim($(this).val());
    var blank_attr = $(this).attr('name');

    if (!blank_value) {
      Status = 1;
      $(this).css('border-color', 'red');
    } else {
      $(this).css('border-color', '');
    }
  });

  if (Status == 1) {
    $('.status-message').html('<span style="color:red;">(*) Marks field are mandatory to fill up** *</span>');
    return false;
  } else {
    console.log('ready to submit')
    //$(this).find(":submit").prop('disabled', true);
    //$('input:submit').trigger("click");
    return true;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Comment `e.preventDefault()` in the line 2 and move it inside `if (Status == 1)`

Below is the modified code

```
$(".form-validation").submit(function(e) {
  //e.preventDefault();

  //check requst product blank field
  var Status = 0;
  $('.requiredCheck').each(function() {
    var blank_value = $.trim($(this).val());
    var blank_attr = $(this).attr('name');

    if (!blank_value) {
      Status = 1;
      $(this).css('border-color', 'red');
    } else {
      $(this).css('border-color', '');
    }
  });

  if (Status == 1) {
    $('.status-message').html('<span style="color:red;">(*) Marks field are mandatory to fill up** *</span>');
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  } else {
    console.log('ready to submit')
    //$(this).find(":submit").prop('disabled', true);
    //$('input:submit').trigger("click");
    return true;
  }
});
```